# How to register additional footer widget areas in Hestia lite child theme?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Hestia lite comes with 3 widget areas in the footer. I created a child theme and I'm trying to add 2 additional widget areas but it's not working. After making the edits, I still only see 3 widget areas available in the customizer.

Here are the lines I modified in class-hestia-footer.php. I added the fifth element in the $footer_sidebars_array, and changed '3' to '5'.

```
    /**
     * Get an array of footer sidevars slugs.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    private function get_footer_sidebars() {
        $footer_sidebars_array = array(
            'footer-one-widgets',
            'footer-two-widgets',
            'footer-three-widgets',
            'footer-four-widgets',
            'footer-five-widgets'
        );
        $number_of_sidebars    = get_theme_mod( 'hestia_nr_footer_widgets', '5' );
        $footer_sidebars_array = array_slice( $footer_sidebars_array, 0, $number_of_sidebars );

        return $footer_sidebars_array;
    }

    /**
     * Get the sidebars class.
     *
     * @return string the sidebar class
     */
    private function the_sidebars_class() {
        $number_of_sidebars = get_theme_mod( 'hestia_nr_footer_widgets', '5' );

        if ( empty( $number_of_sidebars ) ) {
            return 'col-md-4';
        }

        $suffix = abs( 12 / $number_of_sidebars );
        $class  = 'col-md-' . $suffix;

        return $class;
    }
```

Here is the code I modified in class-hestia-public.php:

```
/**
         * Array of sidebars registered in the footer area.
         * The hestia_footer_widget_areas_array filter is used in the PRO version to add the extra forth sidebar.
         */
        $footer_sidebars_array = apply_filters(
            'hestia_footer_widget_areas_array',
            array(
                'footer-one-widgets'   => esc_html__( 'Footer One', 'hestia' ),
                'footer-two-widgets'   => esc_html__( 'Footer Two', 'hestia' ),
                'footer-three-widgets' => esc_html__( 'Footer Three', 'hestia' ),
                'footer-four-widgets'  => esc_html__( 'Footer Four', 'hestia' ),
                'footer-five-widgets'  => esc_html__( 'Footer Five', 'hestia' ),
            )
        );

        /**
         * Number of footer sidebars that need to be registered.
         * This option is available only in the PRO version. In Hestia, the value is always 3.
         */
        $hestia_nr_footer_widgets = is_customize_preview() ? '4' : get_theme_mod( 'hestia_nr_footer_widgets', '5' );

        /**
         * If the Number of widgets areas option is selected, add the specific number of footer sidebars in the main sidebars array to be registered.
         */
        if ( ! empty( $hestia_nr_footer_widgets ) ) {
            $footer_sidebars_array = array_slice( $footer_sidebars_array, 0, $hestia_nr_footer_widgets );
        }

        if ( ! empty( $footer_sidebars_array ) ) {
            $sidebars_array = array_merge( $sidebars_array, $footer_sidebars_array );
        }
```